# Automatically Camera animation (jumping from one object to another)

Tags: python, animation, scripting, camera

I was wondering if there is a script or automation for the Blender Cam to automatically jump from one object to the next.

The background is as follows: I am in the process of creating a photo show in Blender and have about 200 photos in my scene set up as a photo cloud. It is very time-consuming to move the camera manually from photo to photo and to animate this.

In addition, the camera should zoom in or out for 25 frames for each photo, depending on where the camera is coming from (from a photo below - ease out, from a photo above - ease in).

Any ideas?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Sniper Addon](https://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/570-tutorial-sniper-addon-detailed-explanation.html,http://blenderdiplom.com/en/downloads/569-addon-sniper-camera-automation.html)

Comment: Uhhhh - didn't know that this exists. Thx for the help! :)